# In App Store Connect set custom app name and description for specific country

Tags: ios, flutter, deployment, app-store, app-store-connect

How to set a different app name and description for every language in App Store Connect?

For example in Google Play Console you may have one app but set custom app name, description and screen-shots for many different languages. So in result user who visit my app page in GooglePlay see the name of the app in his language.
In App Store Connect I cannot see such an option. I know how to rename whole app - there is no option to manage the translations.
Do you need to add another app in AppStore for another language?

Answer (score 0):

You can localise the app metadata (description) and assets (screenshots) in App Store Connect; while your app is in "prepare for submission" state, simply select the language from the drop-down in the "Version information" section.

[image]

The localised app name is set by the localisation of your app itself.